# Can't locate module in @INC but CPAN says module is up to date

Tags: c++, perl, qt

I'm currently developing a small project with Qt using C++.

My code is calling a Perl script and I got this error:

> Can't locate Proc/ProcessTable.pm in @INC

So I went to install the module and CPAN said:

> Proc::ProcessTable is up to date (0.53).

So i searched a bit and apparently it might be because of two copies of Perl involved. I tried to get the module on a local directory but Qt is still unable to find it. I'm stuck.

Moreover, if I run the Perl script from the command line everything works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I understand you have two different perl installations on the same machine, right?
And your "regular" perl has `Proc/ProcessTable.pm` installed, while the perl used by
your script that is called by C++ has not? There are numerous ways to tell perl where
to search for its `@INC`lude path. If I'm right, I can probably help you out.

Comment: Easiest way - look at the path in the perl script shebang path. Run _that_ perl with `-MCPAN -e shell` and install it.

Comment: That way still says me it's up to date.

Comment: @AlexisCoquard: What does that shebang line say? What happens if you use *that path to perl* with `-MProc::ProcessTable -E'1'`?

Comment: Why are there two installations of perl on this system? Are they usefully different? Can you remove one?

Comment: @Borodin when I run `-MProc::ProcessTable -E'1` I get a `Can't load ... Symbol not found: _PL_curpad`

Comment: @AlexisCoquard: No one has asked what platform you're using this on. Since you're using Qt I imagine it has to be portable, but is this a Linux system, or perhaps Cygwiin on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Use `perl -MCPAN -eshell` but change `perl` to be a direct path to the Perl you want to install the module for.

If that doesn't work, try to print out @INC (e.g. `BEGIN { print "$_\n" for @INC }`) before your failing `use` and compare that to what just `perl -e'print "$_\n" for @INC'` gives.  Something in your code may be removing directories from @INC.

Or you could try

```
force install Proc::ProcessTable
```

in CPAN.

Comment: Unfortunately that's what [**Sobrique** suggested in his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186911/cant-locate-proc-in-inc-but-cpan-says-module-is-up-to-date#comment58092625_35186911) to no apparent effect. But if the OP is to be believed then there's something very odd going on here

Comment: So yes that didn't work then I ran BEGIN { print "$_\n" for @INC } from terminal and from my C++ program and it shows me 2 different directories, so i guess i should be digging that.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you know the path where `Proc/ProcessTable.pm` is installed *and* it is
compatible with the perl version used by your C++ program, you can

1. **either** call perl with `-I`:

   `perl -I /path/to/modules myscript.pl`

   where `/path/to/modules` is the parent of `Proc/ProcessTable.pm`,
   i.e. `/path/to/modules/Proc/ProcessTable.pm` exists.
2. **or** set the environment variable to the modules:

   `export PERL5LIB=/path/to/modules`

   and then start your script. The path given here is prepended to
   the built-in `@INC` path.
3. **or** make your script use the additional path:

   `use lib "/path/to/modules";`

I'd prefer 1. or 2. because hardcoded paths in scripts are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: tried the first one and now the error message changed to: Can't load .. Symbol not found: _PL_curpad. I went through Google and haven't found much :(

Comment: I assume then your module isn't pure perl but also uses/has some `*.so`. Try @Sobrique 's proposal, that sounds very promising.

Comment: @PerlDog: *Relative* hard-coded paths are fine. See [mylib](http://metacpan.org/module/mylib) for example

Comment: if you are getting symbol errors, you likely are pointing to a Proc::ProcessTable that is compiled for a different version or architecture of perl.