# cpan says App::cpanminus is up to date but cpanm doesn't come up in /usr/bin

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

#### SHORT QUESTION

I've  installed `cpanm` on Mac mini G4 Leopard 10.5.8 with perl-8.8.8 using `/usr/bin/cpan -i App::cpanminus` and then `**sudo** /usr/bin/cpan -i App::cpanminus` It said `App::cpanminus is up to date.` but no cpanm is available in `/usr/bin` or anywhere else.

**NOTE** I've looked up the question[Can't locate module in @INC but CPAN says module is up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186911/cant-locate-module-in-inc-but-cpan-says-module-is-up-to-date) and some others which seemed related to my case but they didn't help. Not much information is available in Google searches either.

#### LONG QUESTION

I've  installed `cpanm` on Mac mini G4 Leopard 10.5.8 with perl-8.8.8 using `/usr/bin/cpan -i App::cpanminus`

All the downloading, extracting, compiling, etc went smoothly but at the last step, before installing it as (As Far As I Can Remember / AFAICR) `/usr/bin/cpanm` it stopped with a permission error (AFAICR) So I've repeated the same line with sudo:

```
~ $ sudo /usr/bin/cpan -i App::cpanminus
```

this time it said (again, AFAICR)

```
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /Users/Mac/.cpan/Metadata
  Database was generated on Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:17:02 GMT
App::cpanminus is up to date.
```

and it didn't place the `cpanm` into /usr/bin or any other PATH directory.

Note that I need to use solely `perl, v5.8.8` because it is the only version compatible with some of the system level Perl applications.

When I did a search on the `~/.cpanm` and the default Mac OS X Perl installation folder which is `/System/Library/Perl` no instance of `cpanm` was found. So I gather `cpanm` is not created at all.

I've deleted the `/Users/Mac/.cpan` and repeated the `sudo` install and it ended up with the same message above (again, AFAICR)

So I got stuck in this. I didn't do anything else other than deleting `~/.cpan`

How to install `cpan` on this Mac ?

*Note 2* My question's title might not be best. Anyone is free to edit the title or the question.

**Edit 1**

I've tried the `-f` option but it said `unknown option f`
Here is how it goes:

```
~ $ sudo /usr/bin/cpan -if App::cpanminus
Unknown option: f
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /Users/Mac/.cpan/Metadata
^C
~ $ sudo /usr/bin/cpan -f App::cpanminus
Unknown option: f
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /Users/Mac/.cpan/Metadata
^C
~ $ sudo /usr/bin/cpan -f -i App::cpanminus
Unknown option: f
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /Users/Mac/.cpan/Metadata
  Database was generated on Thu, 09 Dec 2021 18:17:02 GMT
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok
Fetching with LWP:
  http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Going to read /Users/Mac/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
  http://www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Going to read /Users/Mac/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
  Database was generated on Fri, 10 Dec 2021 19:29:02 GMT

  There's a new CPAN.pm version (v2.29) available!
  [Current version is v1.7602]
  You might want to try
    install Bundle::CPAN
    reload cpan
  without quitting the current session. It should be a seamless upgrade
  while we are running...

Fetching with LWP:
  http://www.cpan.org/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Going to read /Users/Mac/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Going to write /Users/Mac/.cpan/Metadata
App::cpanminus is up to date.
```

And surely enough there's still no `cpanm` installed.

**Edit 2**

Output of the `cpan -D App::cpanminus`  (only the meaningful lines included)

```
Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes] yes
Reading '/Users/Mac/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 10 Dec 2021 19:29:02 GMT
App:cpanminus
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (no description)
    M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz
    (no installation file)
    Installed: not installed
    CPAN:      1.7044  Not up to date
    Tatsuhiko Miyagawa (MIYAGAWA)
    miyagawa@bulknews.net
```

Comment: *"but no cpanm is available in /usr/bin or anywhere else"* : I tried to install `cpanm` like you on macOS 12.0.1, as you can see from my [install log](https://pastebin.com/7SpuBUeH), it installed `cpanm` into `/usr/local/bin/` and the module `App::cpanmiunus` in `/Library/Perl/5.30/App/cpanminus.pm`. Can you check if you got anything in those directories?

Comment: I've just checked the `/usr/local/bin` and cpanm is nowhere. I've checked `/Library/Perl` again it's nowhere. I've searched the whole `/usr` again nowhere. That cpanm is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Try executing just `sudo /usr/bin/cpan` without any arguments. It should give you a prompt. At the prompt, type `force install App::cpanminus` and post the output here.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note:

- The *cpan* output should tell you where it installed things. Do you have the output? To try again, you can force install with `cpan -f` to see what happened.
- The *.cpan/* directory is just a work directory for CPAN.pm. However, you can go into its *build/* directory and find the directory for the thing you are having trouble with to look at its build files. The *Makefile* will have settings such as `INSTALLBIN` and `INSTALLSITEBIN` (and some others) that notes where it decided to install things. Apple has typically set these to whatever they wanted for you already, so it's slightly different than the default *perl* behavior.
- You've likely installed the cpanm script in one of perl's directories. Perl modules typically do not install into a common directory without you doing something special. There's likely a *bin* directory at the same level as the *lib/* directory. See where you installed the module and then look for that *bin/*

```
$ cpan -D App::cpanminus
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/Users/brian/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 10 Dec 2021 19:29:02 GMT
App::cpanminus
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (no description)
    M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.34.0/lib/site_perl/5.34.0/App/cpanminus.pm
    Installed: 1.7044
    CPAN:      1.7044  up to date
    Tatsuhiko Miyagawa (MIYAGAWA)
    miyagawa@bulknews.net

$ ls -l /usr/local/perls/perl-5.34.0/bin/cpanm
-r-xr-xr-x  1 brian  wheel  302800 Jun 23 18:53 /usr/local/perls/perl-5.34.0/bin/cpanm
```

- I like to leave the Perl programs in that bin directory and make links to them if I want them somewhere else in my path ([Make links to per version tools](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/03/make-links-to-per-version-tools/).
- The `-i` switch to *cpan* is just extra typing. It's implied in almost every case where you would use it.
- You get the permission error because you are using the system Perl and installing things into the directories it set up. Apple is pretty good about segregating that, but I don't remember how well they were doing that back then. A system update (heh, in your case unlikely ;) might overwrite or delete your work. Many people use a separate, user-installed *perl* and pretend the system *perl* does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the 1st section, see the edit 1 which I've added to the question (cpan -f is problematic on this Mac, too) For the 2nd section, there's no _build_ directory under `~/.cpan` There's only a Metadata file and a sources folder and no _build_ dir thereunder. For the 3rd section, see the edit 2. I didn't know `-i`switch could be dropped. Good to know.

Comment: What happens when you install a modern CPAN.pm?

Comment: I've lost hope on the `cpan` and decided to install `cpanm` manually i.e. I've downloaded the tar.gz package and did `/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL` and `make` and `cpanm` is installed finally. Then I've done `/usr/bin/cpanm FCGI` (FCGI is the ultimate target) It didn't install (couldn't pass the test) So I've performed a manual install for the FCGI too. It stopped with `cc1 error: unrecognized command line option -Wno-error...` Surely this is compiler specific. Upgraded gcc to 4.2 and it compiled fine and  FCGI is installed, finally. Phew :)

Comment: Yeah, you are on a pretty old system there, so it's difficult to provide support.